# Mostrar GIF enquanto página carrega

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5

Preciso que um GIF fique funcionando enquanto a página carrega. Eu já tentei alguns jeitos mas nenhum funcionou.
E que quando página carregar apareça o **Concluído!**. 
Mais ou menos como o acontece [neste site](http://coffeeup.com.br/).

Comment: Tem o evento onload http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp Ou tenta exibir o código fonte lá e ver como foi implementado.

Comment: Se quiser fazer sem dependências externas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66039/como-colocar-uma-gif-antes-de-exibir-a-p%C3%A1gina-do-site/67568#67568

Comment: Também pode pensar em adicionar uma biblioteca de terceiros como pace.js

Comment: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Na verdade o que acontece nesse site é que ele coloca por cima do conteúdo um DIV que cobre tudo e assim que o conteúdo é carregado (`document.load`) ele esconde o DIV com um efeito de `fadeOut`.

Refiz isso no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/SL3R7/1/) pra ficar mais fácil (apesar que você irá ver melhor o efeito na sua página diretamente).

HTML

```
<div id="preloader"><h1>CARREGANDO</h1></div>

<div id="conteudo">
    <img src="http://3rdbillion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/d6c7c50b9b49412a2ad9f847dcbaeeba13.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #000;
}
#preloader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Esconde preloader
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#preloader').fadeOut(1500);//1500 é a duração do efeito (1.5 seg)
    });

});
```

No lugar no "carregando" é só colocar sua tag `<img>` com um GIF que você quiser. Apesar de que já é possível fazer uma animação simples com CSS3 assim você não precisa usar imagem.

Comment: Muito bom, valeu mesmo.