# Como faço para exibir uma barra de carregamento quanto minha página php executa uma tarefa?

Tags: php

Tenho uma página para enviar um lista de email em PHP. Preciso que enquanto a página está executando o envio apareça algo mostrando que há tarefa em andamento.

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: É tão longo assim o envio de email? o que geralmente é feito colocar um gif de algo girando ou qualquer outra coisa que de a impressão que o trabalho está executando.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você pode por no botão de submit algum efeito, como este exemplo que o Boostrap utiliza.

[http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-stateful](http://Loading%20Bootstrap)

Você pode visualizar algo relacionado no seguinte post: 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8584/37291

Espero ter ajudado!